# Function continuity and uniform continuity

Tags: real-analysis, examples-counterexamples

I have been through a proof that $F(x)=x^2$ is not uniformly continuous on $(-\infty,+\infty)$. Does it mean it is not continuous on $(-\infty,+\infty)$? Thanks for reading.

Comment: Uniformaly conitinuous is just a "stronger" form of continuity, it means your $\delta=\delta(\epsilon ,F)$ i.e. is independent of the point $x_0$ you look at. However, the fucntion is still continuous, as you can find a $\delta=\delta(\epsilon , F, x_0$ for every $\epsilon > 0$ and $x_0$. Overall, uniform continuity implies continuity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uniform continuity is a much stronger condition than continuity.

If $f$ is uniformly continuous on $A\subseteq \Bbb R\implies$ $f$ is continuous therein.

Whereas if $f$ is not uniformly continuous on $A\subseteq \Bbb R$, nothing can be said about the continuity of $f$ on $A\subseteq \Bbb R\;$  i.e. $f$ may or may not be continuous on $A$.

Also, your function $F(x)=x^2$, is continuous on the whole of $\Bbb R$. This is how it follows.

Let $\epsilon >0$ be given and $x_0\in \Bbb R$ be arbitrary.

Consider  $$ |F(x)-F(x_0)|=|x^2  -x_{0}^{2}| =|(x +x_{0})(x -x_{0})| = |x +x_{0}||x -x_{0}|  \le(|x|+|x_0|)|x-x_0|$$

We now make use of the following inequality which is a consequence of the Triangle Inequality $$||a|-|b||\le|a-b|$$
For $|x-x_0|<1$, we have $$||x|-|x_0||\le|x-x_0|<1\implies|x|-|x_0|<1\implies|x|<1+|x_0|$$

and hence
 $$|x^2 -x_{0}^{2} | \le(|x|+|x_0|)|x-x_0|<(1+2|x_0|)|x-x_0|\tag1$$

Now choose $\delta=\min\left(1,\frac{\displaystyle\epsilon}{\displaystyle1+2|x_0|}\right)$.

Since $|x-x_0|<\delta\le 1 $ then equation $(1)$ holds, $$|x^2-x_{0}^{2}| <(1+2|x_0|)|x-x_0|$$

Again, as $\delta \le \frac{\displaystyle\epsilon}{\displaystyle(1+2|x_0|)}$

So for $|x-x_0|<\delta$, $$|F(x)-F(x_0)|=|x^2 -x_{0}^{2}| < (1+2|x_0|)|x-_0|<(1+2|x_0|)\frac{\displaystyle\epsilon}{\displaystyle(1+2|x_0|)}=\epsilon$$

Thus, $$\lim_{x\to x_0}F(x)=F(x_0)$$

Hence $F$ is continuous on $\Bbb R$.

So in this particular example we observe that $F$ is not uniformly continuous on $\Bbb R$ but it is continuous on $\Bbb R$

Comment: What I think is missing me is the definition of uniformly continuous. What does that mean? Thanks for your quick reply!

Comment: @PedroGomes You might find this immensely helpful. http://math.stackexchange.com/a/293562/135775 In the case of continuity, the choice of $\delta$ depends on $\epsilon$ as well as the the point $x_0$. So as your $x_0$ changes, the choice of your $\delta$ will change. Look at my answer, the $\delta$ that I have chosen  depends on $x_0$ and hence it will be different for different values of $x_0$. On the contrary if I can define my $\delta $ in such a way that it does not depend on $x_0$, then we say that the function is uniformly continuous.

Comment: @PedroGomes So, in the case of uniform continuity, not only do I have to find a $\delta$ (as we do in the case of continuity), but I have to also see to it that it does not depend on $x_0$. So, you can think of a uniformly continuous function as a function which is continuous and which also satisfies the extra condition mentioned above.

Comment: Got it! Thanks a lot!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!